# Expectation of product of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Let $X,Y$, two random variables which are indicators. Lets assume $P(X=1)=p$ and $P(Y=1)=q$ for some $0 \le p,q \le 1$.

I've understood that: $E[XY] = P(X=1, Y=1)$. How to show it?

$$E[XY] = \sum_{i=0}^1 XY\cdot Pr(?)$$

I guess it should be $Pr(X=i, Y=i)$ and of course, when $i=0$ the all expression equals to $0$.

But, why is it $Pr(X=i, Y=i)$? I'd be glad for both algebraic and intuitive explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be
$$E[XY] = \sum_{i=0}^1 \sum_{j=0}^1 i j\cdot P(X=i, Y=j)$$
and if you write all four members of the above sum, three of them is egual to zero:
$$E[XY] = 0 \cdot 0 \cdot P(X=0, Y=0) + 1 \cdot 0 \cdot P(X=1, Y=0)\\
+ 0 \cdot 1 \cdot P(X=0, Y=1)+ 1 \cdot 1 \cdot P(X=1, Y=1)$$

Comment: Okay, but why is it $P(X=i,Y=j)$?

Comment: Because it is possible that for example $X=0$ and $Y=1$. If you think only about $P(X=i,Y=i)$, you miss some possibilities.

Comment: What I have used is definition of expected value for two-dimensional random variable. I guess you try to use definition of expected value for one-dimensional variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the random variables $X$ and $Y$ can take only the values $0$ and $1$, so does the random variable $XY$. This random variable take the value $1$ only on the set $\{X=1\}\cap \{Y=1\}$.